# Safely remove contents from .Private folder : Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: encryption, directory, disk-usage, delete, secure-erase

I have a problem with my growing .Private folder.
I want to keep the encryption going but want to remove the stale copies of the files under .Private folder in my home directory.

1) Is it possible to delete the contents safely from .Private folder?

2) If yes how?

Answer (score 0):

Bad Idea! The encrypted files in `~/.Private` are the ACTUAL files, encrypted. Don't mess with them!

What you think of as your files are artifacts of the `ecryptfs` file system driver, which, using the encrypted files in `~/.Private`, produces the files you see.